# DOM Storage if Available

Tags: android, webview

I'm wanting to enable DOM-storage in the Android Webkit-Webview.

I tried [setDomStorageEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled%28boolean%29), but it only compiles when I set it to compile for API 7+. Is there any way to keep compatibility with older OS, but set the browser to use this if it is available?

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use simple functionality not available to all API levels, you can generally do this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1) {
    webView.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: It still says The method setDomStorageEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type WebSettings

Comment: Have you set your project build target to API level 7 or later? The code above stops the method being called on older versions of Android, but you'll need to target level 7 or later for the compiler to find the method.

Comment: You mean <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="11" />? yes, I have that.

Comment: These are different to the build target. In Eclipse, right click on your project and select Properties. In the left hand pane, click 'Android' and look at which checkbox is checked. This is the Project Build Target.

Comment: It actually causes an exception when run in older Android, though: java.lang.VerifyError: E/AndroidRuntime(843):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)